# Can I run both ExpressJS and Nginx at the same time?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, debian

I have been using Nginx on my Debian VPS to host my website for some time now, and I would like to run a NodeJS app on the same droplet, so I looked at my options and saw about ExpressJS.

From what I understood it behaves as a web server but in JS (?)

I have looked at the tutorials to get started and got something working on my Windows PC, but I would like to know if I can run both an ExpressJS server AND an nginx server on my Debian VPS, on the same port, without screwing up everything ? (I don't want to erase my current website)

I would like to have it so Nginx is used for any directory EXCEPT for ExpressJS's directory which would be something like "var/www/html/expressapp/...".

Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I would love to understand how to use both at once

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but NGINX can be configured as a proxy which sits in front of any server (including Express).  So, you could configure it so that certain URLS do one thing in NGINX (like serve static content) while other URLs go to your express server.  The `var/www/html/expressapp/..` doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me because a request is either forwarded to your Express server or or NGINX does something else with it.

Comment: NGINX has (in it's configuration) rich URL matching logic so you can decide what you want NGINX to do with any URL such as serve static content from location A or serve static content from location B or forward to port X on host Y.  Those capabilities are all in the NGINX configuration documentation.

Comment: sorry i'm mistaken, i thought nginx was the web server here, but in fact i'm running apache so the real question was "can i run apache and expressjs at the same time" and the answer you gave me is "yes, nginx allows you to chose whether you want to use express or apache for the chosen urls", right ? thanks for the replies !

Comment: nginx can serve multiple roles.  It can be a web server and directly serve static content.  Or, it can be a proxy for some URLS and forward the requests that match that URL pattern to your app server.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanations, I got it working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can: You just need to set up an upstream on nginx configuration, and point it to the port your express is using, that way the traffic meant to go to your nodejs app is automaticaly rerouted to your express server.

In my case, i used express to serve an api, and basicaly i just pointed everything going through /api to my node server.

Someone made a good sample right here: https://gist.github.com/turtlesoupy/3072833

The key elements here are "upstream" and proxy options.

Comment: Thanks ! I got it working.

Here is what i added to **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** :
`
_location /someurl { proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; }_

Comment: Would you mind to accept the answer then, it might help someone else ^^